# angularjs location scope

Tags: angularjs

I have some issue with AngularJS scope and location. Here is an example :

```
function CreateAccountCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    ...
    $http.post(url,$scope.form).
        success(function(data){
            $location.path('/'); // I need to transfert data to the location 
        }
}
```

My problem is : I want to transfer the data to the / controller, I thought to use the rootScope but I don't think it is the best way to do this.

Any idea ?

Comment: To pass data between controllers you can create a shared service that is injected in both controllers, or if the data is not complex just call / with some parameters and then access them using $routeParams.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *$rootScope* to send data between controllers. *$routeParams* doesn't allow send complex data structures.
Let's see it.

Assign returned data of success callback to variable in *$rootScope*. 
Navigate to the AccountController.

```
function CreateAccountCtrl($scope, $http, $location,$rootScope ) {
    ...
    $http.post(url,$scope.form).
        success(function(data){
            $rootScope.accountInfo = data; 
            $location.path('/account');
        }
}
```

Configure the route in the *$routeProvider*:

```
$routeProvider.when('/account', {
    template: 'account.html',
    controller: AccountCntl  
});
```

In the AccountController can access the data on *$rootScope*.

```
function AccountCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.accountInfo = $rootScope.accountInfo;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best method so far to achieve this. the only problem would be if a different controller loaded with the wrong model on rootscope.

Answer (score 1):

Use the $routeParams service.

```
function CreateAccountCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    ...
    $http.post(url,$scope.form).
        success(function(data){
            $location.path('/account/' + data.accountId);
        }
}
```

Configure the route in the $routeProvider:

```
$routeProvider.when('/account/:accountId', {
    template: 'account.html',
    controller: AccountCntl  
});
```

Your AccountController can now access the data:

```
function AccountCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.accountId = $routeParams.accountId;
}
```